# Assign Text (Label) to values in SQL Query Result

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

All data in my tables are in numeric format. For example,

```
class   sex subject medium
    5     1   1       1
    1     1   1       2
    4     3   3       1
    5     1   3       2
    1     1   3       1
    3     1   2       2
    1     2   2       2
```

Other Table contains Description to each value for each table. For Example,

```
Table       Column      value       text
Student     class       1            1ST
Student     class       2            2ND
Student     class       3            3RD
Student     class       4            4TH
Student     class       5            5TH
Student     sex         1            male
Student     sex         2            female
Student     sex         3            creator
Student     medium      1            English
Student     medium      2            Hindi
```

I am trying to provide a text (label to each column when user queries). I have been able to do it for one column. For example,

```
SELECT class, sex, avg(total_marks) as total
FROM (
SELECT value, text as sex
FROM Label 
WHERE table_name = 'Student' and
    Column = 'class' or
 ) AS Label INNER JOIN  Student on value = class
GROUP BY class, sex
```

This results in

```
class   sex total
1ST     1   64.80
1ST     2   59.66
2ND     1   78.96
2ND     2   96.97
3RD     1   52.67
3RD     2   81.77
4TH     1   61.99
4TH     2   99.78
5TH     1   72.90
5TH     2   70.59
```

Instead of 1 / 2 /3 in sex I want to show male, female and creator. Select and Group by columns can be more than 4 at times. I am using MySql and PHP Laravel to do this.

Comment: Hi there! Why don't you show us what you've done so far in Laravel?

Answer (score 1):

I guess I found the answer. Any suggestions are most welcome.

```
SELECT T1.class, T2.sex,  SUM(weight) 
FROM household_characteristics 
    INNER JOIN (SELECT value_label_name as code, value_label_value FROM labels      
WHERE table_name = 'Student' and columns = 'class' ) AS T1 ON T1.code =   Student.class
INNER JOIN (SELECT value_label_name as code, value_label_value FROM labels      
WHERE table_name = 'Student' and columns = 'sex' ) AS T2 ON T2.code = Student.sex
GROUP BY  class, sex
```